# How to capture standard output on iPhone? (for development purpose)

Tags: iphone, capture, stdio

How to capture standard I/O of iPhone?

For private development purpose, not for public release.
I'm trying some kind of irregular things.

ex)

1. Printing network stream input to both of iPhone console, and screen.
2. Redirecting console output to network stream.
3. Redirecting NSLog output to my own program.
4. ... (and more)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this isn't what you're looking for, but you can watch/copy/save the Console of your device in the Xcode Organizer (Window->Organizer).